# Using Angular 7, how do I call wikipedia api and return the results into a model?

Tags: angular, typescript, wikipedia-api

I am trying to access the Wikipedia API with Angular 7, and the results continue to be null.

When running from the Wikipedia API site, with the following:
**https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/Addax?redirect=true** 
I get results in a properly formatted JSON string.

When the same query is run from my app, the response body is empty.

Here's the request:

```
export class WikirestService {
  constructor( private http:  HttpClient) { }

  getWiki(title: string) {
    const tempTitle = title.replace(' ', '_') + '?redirect=true';
    const baseUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/';
    return this.http.get<WikiSummary>(baseUrl+tempTitle);
  }
}
```

and the WikiSummary Model is:

```
 export class WikiSummary {
      type?:          string;
      title?:         string;
      displaytitle?:  string;
      namespace?:     Namespace;
      wikibase_item?: string;
      titles?:        Titles;
      pageid?:        number;
      thumbnail?:     Originalimage;
      originalimage?: Originalimage;
      lang?:          string;
      dir?:           string;
      revision?:      string;
      tid?:           string;
      timestamp?:     Date;
      description?:   string;
      content_urls?:  ContentUrls;
      api_urls?:      APIUrls;
      extract?:       string;
      extract_html?:  string;
    }
```

I expect the model to be populated, but it is always null.  Even when I log the results, they are null.
Call from component:

```
this.wikiRest.getWiki(this.title).subscribe(data => { temp = data; });
```

I've spent several hours struggling with this and could really use some guidance.  This is the first time I've had an issue calling an External API.

Comment: have you checked in the network tab what the actualy return value is ?

Comment: it might be angular CORS filtering oO I think its quite strict about that to make sure check the console while youre doing the request

Comment: I managed to get a correct result back and work with that. I don't really see what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, I tried it (without the unknown data types). it works without issues.  Perhaps you are trying to check the value of temp outside of the async call??? the value of data is only available withing the result (without any special actions)

```
   this.wikiRest.getWiki('Addax').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data.description);
    }, err => { console.log('something went wrong' + err)
  }); 



getWiki(title: string) {
  const tempTitle = title.replace(' ', '_') + '?redirect=true';
  const baseUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/summary/';
  return this.http.get<WikiSummary>(baseUrl+tempTitle);
}

export class WikiSummary {
  type?:          string;
  title?:         string;
  displaytitle?:  string;
 // namespace?:     Namespace;
  wikibase_item?: string;
  //titles?:        Titles;
  pageid?:        number;
  //thumbnail?:     Originalimage;
 // originalimage?: Originalimage;
  lang?:          string;
  dir?:           string;
  revision?:      string;
  tid?:           string;
  timestamp?:     Date;
  description?:   string;
  //content_urls?:  ContentUrls;
  //api_urls?:      APIUrls;
  extract?:       string;
  extract_html?:  string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's exactly what was going on.  I went so far down the rabbit trail I lost my bearings!